# Excel - Formula in pivot-table (subtract fixed value from summarized value)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have a workbook that is supposed to track the extra hours I put in at work, eg. thos that are over a normal workday.

It has several timestamps that shows when work is started and ended, like this:

| Work Start | Work End | Result (minutes) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 31.01.22 08:00 | 31.01.22 15:00 | 420 |
| 31.01.22 18:00 | 31.01.22 21:00 | 180 |
| 01.02.22 08:00 | 01.02.22 16:30 | 510 |
| 02.02.22 08:00 | 02.02.22 15:30 | 450 |

In a pivot-table I have summarized the values to show how much I work each day:

| Date | Minutes |
| --- | --- |
| 31.01.22 | 600 |
| 01.02.22 | 510 |
| 02.02.22 | 450 |

**However;** I only want to show the time I put in beyond a normal workday, like 7,5 hours. I just cant find out where to put in that calculation.

My organization does not allow me to use visual basic or install any add-ons.

Comment: Insert a Calculated Field into your Pivot Table with the formula `=Minutes-(7.5*60)`. Amend the 7.5 as required.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change how you record the information slightly you can do this all in formulas without a pivot table.

First you will need a column that only has the date value for each of the working days i.e.

| date | starttime | endtime | minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 31/01/2022 | 08:00 | 15:00 | 420 |
| 31/01/2022 | 15:00 | 21:00 | 180 |
| 01/02/2022 | 08:00 | 16:30 | 510 |
| 02/02/2022 | 08:00 | 15:30 | 450 |

If you then create another table that only has one row for each date.

You can then enter the below formula into the cell nextto the date of this second table

```
=SUMIF(A:A,E3,C:C)
```

A:A should be the first column of your first table

E3 should be the first cell in the first column of your second table

C:C should be the column in your first table with the summed time in

This formual will then add up all the values that happen on the same day i.e. 600 for 31/01/2022

You can then add in the followign formual into the next column of your second table, this will covert the minutes time into hours

```
=F3/60
```

F3 is the cell that contains the total sumed time in your second table

Finally you can add in the following formula in a column at the end of your second table, this will then calculate the additional hours above 7.5 each day

```
=G3-7.5
```

G3 is the cell that contains the summed hours divided by 60